# How to weight samples with sklearns's cross_validate for scoring only?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, sampling

I am running a regression task on a dataset which is composed of both authentic and augmented samples. The augmented samples are generated by jittering the authentic ones. I would like to select the best performing model with cross-validation with `sklearn`.

For this I would like to:

- Train the model on a set that is comprised of both the authentic and augmented samples. I do not want the fitting procedure to take the origin of the sample into account (i.e. it should be equivalent to run `estimator.fit(..., sample_weights = [1,1,..., 1]`).
- Score the models based on their performance **on the authentic samples only**. For this, I thought of setting the weight of augmented (resp. authentic) samples to 0 (resp. 1).

How to achieve this with sklearn's [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html)?

I tried the following:

```py
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error, make_scorer
import numpy as np

n_smpl, n_feats = 100, 5
arr_source = np.random.random((n_smpl, n_feats))
arr_target = np.random.random((n_smpl, n_feats))
arr_weight = np.random.randint(0, 2, n_smpl)  # 0 for augmented, 1 for authentic

model = RandomForestRegressor()
kfold_splitter = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=7, shuffle=True)
my_scorers = {
    "r2_weighted": make_scorer(r2_score, sample_weight=arr_weight),
    "mse_weighted": make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False, sample_weight=arr_weight)
}

cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(model, arr_source, arr_target, scoring = my_scorers, cv=kfold_splitter)
```

But this returns `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [20, 20, 100]`. I understand that this happens because cross_validate is not able to split the sample weights according to the folds.

Is there any way to get this to run through cross-validate? Or any other method?

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for in the [Metadata-routing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/metadata_routing.html#metadata-routing) feature which enables to pass different parameters to the scorer and the estimator.

The steps to use it are:

1. Enable the metadata routing: `sklearn.set_config(enable_metadata_routing=True)`
2. Turn off the routing for the estimator: `RandomForestRegressor().set_fit_request(sample_weight=False)`
3. Turn on the routing for the scorers: `make_scorer(r2_score).set_score_request(sample_weight=True)`
4. Pass the sample weights to the cross-validation parameters: `model_selection.cross_validate(..., params={"sample_weight": arr_weight})`

The full code looks like:

```py
from sklearn import model_selection, set_config
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error, make_scorer
import numpy as np

n_smpl, n_feats = 100, 5
arr_source = np.random.random((n_smpl, n_feats))
arr_target = np.random.random((n_smpl, n_feats))
arr_weight = np.random.randint(0, 2, n_smpl)  # 0 for augmented, 1 for authentic

set_config(enable_metadata_routing=True)
model = RandomForestRegressor().set_fit_request(sample_weight=False)
kfold_splitter = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=7, shuffle=True)
my_scorers = {
    "r2_weighted": make_scorer(r2_score).set_score_request(sample_weight=True),
    "mse_weighted": make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False).set_score_request(sample_weight=True)
}

cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(model, arr_source, arr_target, scoring = my_scorers, cv=kfold_splitter, params={"sample_weight": arr_weight})
```